# What is the lucene query syntax for not in list?

Tags: syntax, lucene

I've done some google searching and haven't found exactly what I'm looking for.  Basically I have a list of item in a lucene index, and I start with getting a set of items.  I want to follow up that query with a new one where the old items aren't returned.  I felt like I might use something like a `* and NOT:(id1 id2 id3...)` but I'm not sure what the syntax for that would be?

Answer (score 6):

The syntax is: `*:* -(id1 id2 id3)`

`*:*` will include everything and `-` removes the set represented in the parantheses. `(id1 id2 id3)` means id1 OR id2 OR id3.